# Can't use Arquillian with remote WL

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, jboss-arquillian

I want to use arquillian to create unit tests for a ADF project. The tests should run on a remote WL 10.3.6.

With a weld-container everything is fine but if I change to remote WL I always get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer.
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletUtil.determineBaseURI(ServletUtil.java:64)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletURIHandler.locateTestServlet(ServletURIHandler.java:60)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:84)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:120)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:111)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$6.evaluate(Arquillian.java:263)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:226)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I removed all unneeded stuff to have a very basic setup / project:

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.company</groupId>
<artifactId>test-arquilian</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                 <source>1.6</source>
                 <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Alpha2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**arquillian.xml**

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<container qualifier="wls" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="adminUrl">t3://localhost:7001</property>
        <property name="adminUserName">weblogic</property>
        <property name="adminPassword">Welcome1</property>
        <property name="target">DefaultServer</property>
        <property name="wlsHome">C:\space\wls_10_3_6\wlserver_10.3</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
</arquillian>
```

**FirstArquilianTest.java**

```
package de.company;

import junit.framework.Assert;    
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class FirstArquilianTest {

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void failTest() {
    Assert.fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

When I start the test I will receive the following output:

```
Sep 13, 2013 10:51:34 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.WebLogicDeployerClient deploy
INFO: Starting weblogic.Deployer to deploy the test artifact.
Sep 13, 2013 10:51:38 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.WebLogicDeployerClient forkWebLogicDeployer
INFO: weblogic.Deployer appears to have terminated successfully.
Sep 13, 2013 10:51:38 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.WebLogicDeployerClient undeploy
INFO: Starting weblogic.Deployer to undeploy the test artifact.
Sep 13, 2013 10:51:41 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.WebLogicDeployerClient forkWebLogicDeployer
INFO: weblogic.Deployer appears to have terminated successfully.
```

If I add a breakpoint I can see that the application is deloyed to the weblogic (in weblogic console). Here everything looks right.

Maybe anyone can help me with this exception?

**Update:**
I tried it with

```
<groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
<artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

but it has the same effect / exception.

I exported the artefact as mentioned in the comments. Here is the output:
[image: war content]
[image: inner jar content]

**Update:**
I changed the dep to "arquillian-wls-remote-10.3" and now I receive this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.company.FirstArquilianTest
at         weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:158)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:126)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:90)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3739)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3705)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2282)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2181)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

After changing to **"arquillian-wls-remote-10.3"** an ear instead of a war is build. The ear has much more content (web.xml, etc.). Will upload an example.
Here is the zipped ear-File: http://www.guigarage.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ear.zip

**Solution**
You need at least one EJB in your deployment. If no EJB is specified the ear can't be deployed to WL. After adding a EJB everithing was fine. The WL-Test from Arquillian is a great example: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-wls/blob/master/wls-remote-10.3/src/test/java/org/jboss/arquillian/container/wls/remote_10_3/WebLogicDeployJarTest.java

Comment: You might want to export the deployment and examine it. Refer [this section of the guide](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_rinse_and_repeat/#export_the_deployment) for details on how to export the deployment. Posting the contents here would help. I suspect the deployment is not being enhanced by Arquillian with the required JARs.

Comment: I tried to use arquillian-wls-remote-12.1 - 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT with the same result

Comment: Ah ok, got your problem...See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLS 10.3.x if I'm not mistaken uses only the Java EE 5 APIs, and hence you'll need to use the `arquillian-wls-remote-10.3` artifact for this series of the WLS containers.

`arquillian-wls-remote-12.1` is to be used only for WLS 12c.

As for testing JAR deployments on Java EE 5 containers, Arquillian chooses to wrap JARs inside an EAR file to make them deployable. Ideally for Java EE 5 containers, you would create EJB modules as JAR files, and hence this would make sense in such a scenario.

I do not know what you want to test yet, but the advice here is: your ShrinkWrap deployment should mirror the actual deployment you make in production as much as possible. If you're testing EJBs, you should prepare a deployment that includes the EJBs in the same structure as your project build output. If you're testing a POJO that resides in a utility JAR eventually packaged in a WAR/EAR file, then by all means create a ShrinkWrap `JavaArchive` for the JAR, but wrap it inside a `WebArchive` or `EnterpriseArchive` for Java EE 5 containers. You may find that Java EE 6 containers operate differently so you will need revisit these guidelines.

If you want an example test, on how JAR based deployments are tested in WLS 10.3.x, you could take a look at [this test in the Arquillian WLS container test suite](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-wls/blob/master/wls-remote-10.3/src/test/java/org/jboss/arquillian/container/wls/remote_10_3/WebLogicDeployJarTest.java).

Comment: Sounds like a good idea :) Now i get: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.company.FirstArquilianTest

Comment: That's a bit odd given that the deployment contains the class file in the screenshot. You may want to re-verify the exported deployment.

Comment: I dont think it matters anymore. Please see my updated answer and let me know if it doesn't help.